# jquery target multiple title attributes

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the below code which works fine.

```
    <div id="testdiv"></div>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td class="test" title="two">2</td>
            <td class="test" title="one">1</td>
            <td class="test" title="three">3</td>
        </tr>
    </table>

    <script>
        if(jQuery("td[title='three']").length == 0) {
          jQuery('#testdiv').append('<p>no td</p>')
        }
        else
        {
          jQuery('#testdiv').append('<p>yes td</p>')
        }
    </script>
```

However I want to say if either title one or three are present. So I tried editing the first line of my script to look like this.

```
if(jQuery("td[title='three']").length == 0 || jQuery("td[title='one']").length == 0) {
```

But for some reason it seems as though both three and one need to be there for my statement to be true?

But if I replace the || with the && it works how I want it to?  Why is it that the && is working like an || here or am I missing something here?

[See fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aaronk85/bRN3y/) for example

Comment: You're asking if either is *not* there. Change `==` to `>` in the `||` version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`||` is OR, `&&` is AND so if you need *both* conditions to be met you have to use `&&`, but you can make this a bit shorter. I'm using `$` for convenience but you can replace with `jQuery`:

```
var exists = $('td[title=one],td[title=three]').length;
$('#testdiv').append('<p>'+ (exists ? 'yes' : 'no') +' td</p>');
```

Answer (score 2):

`||` means "inclusive or."  With `||` you are saying if either `title=three` does not exist *or* `title=one` does not exist, show `no td`.  That is to say if one *does* exist, it will still say `no td`.  Both need to exist if you use `||` in the way that you are.  I think it may make more sense to you if you reverse the conditions:

```
    if(jQuery("td[title='three']").length > 0
       || jQuery("td[title='one']".length > 0
    ) {
      jQuery('#testdiv').append('<p>yes td</p>')
    }
    else
    {
      jQuery('#testdiv').append('<p>no td</p>')
    }
```